# « Import » et « importation » : Quelles sont les différences de sens et d'usage entre les deux mots ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, informatique

Je ne parviens pas à trouver quelle est la différence entre « import » et « importation » en français.

Un collègue soutient qu'« importation » est plus adapté au domaine du commerce (ex : *Importation de marchandises*) et « import » au domaine de l'informatique (ex : *Import de données*). Un autre dit le contraire.

Existe-t-il des différences de sens et/ou d'usage entre les deux mots ?

Comment: C'est facile, c'est la même qu'entre « export » et « exportation » ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les mots *import* ou *export* appartiennent à la langue anglaise mais ils sont « parfois utilisé[s] dans divers contextes et attesté[s] dans certains ouvrages » en langue française (GDT) ; on parle d'[importation](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8428940) et d'[exportation](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8392990). En ce qui a trait au mot composé [*import-export*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8392925), c'est un emprunt intégral de 1885 (GDT) basé sur un syntagme attesté chez [Jules Laforgue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Laforgue), *import et export* (DHLF). Comme on l'a mentionné [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32779), il y a pu y avoir des emprunts ponctuels, par exemple didactiques. On rejette personnellement la qualification d'abréviation : en effet une abréviation qui ne contient pas la lettre finale du mot abrégé doit [normalement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3401) contenir le point abréviatif (par exemple l'abréviation d'expéditeur est « [exp.](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1797) »), ce qui n'est pas le cas ici ; il pourrait s'agir d'une forme tronquée à l'oral du mot importation.

Comment: Une apocope en quelque sorte…

Answer (score 6):

Pour moi "import" n'est que l'abréviation d'importation, avec le même sens donc. Import est beaucoup moins utilisé qu'importation (cfr ngram viewer), et, à ma connaissance, on le rencontre surtout dans l'expression import-export mais rarement ailleurs.

Answer (score 2):

Normalement on ne devrait trouver ni « import » ni « export » dans le français sauf dans le mot composé « import-export » : ces mots ne figurent pas dans le TLFi ; on ne trouve pas non plus le mot dans le Larousse, où ne figure que l'acception propre à la [Belgique](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/import/41935).

On trouve cependant dans L'internaute que le mot est une [abréviation](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/import/).

> import , nom masculin
>     Sens 1
>       Abréviation du terme importation, qui désigne l'action d'importer, c'est-à-dire d'introduire dans un pays des marchandises, de la main-d'oeuvre, etc., provenant de pays étrangers.

On trouve dans le [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/import) l'acception « [montant](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/import) » propre seulement à la Belgique ; on trouve aussi en français français le mot « import » selon [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/import) et une de ses acception est bien « importation »; le mot a un pluriel, imports. Donc malgré l'étrange abstraction qui est faite de ce mot dans le TLFi et le Larousse, force est de conclure qu'il fait bien partie du langage, même si assez rare, et cela pas seulement en tant que nouveau terme informatique signifiant une variété de choses, mais en tant que terme signifiant soit « importation » soit « intromission » soit « acclimatation ».

Comment: Il ne faut pas se fier aveuglément aux courbes de Google ngram. D'une part, la fréquence absolue est basse, d'autre part beaucoup des occurrences d'import ou export trouvées par cet outil sont des abréviations ou de faux positifs (texte en anglais mal classifié, texte français mal retranscrit). On trouve aussi quelques ouvrages informatiques traitant des instructions `import` et `export`, orthographiées en anglais, présentes dans quelques langages de programmation.

Comment: @jlliagre Je comprends bien cela et il semble qu'il y ait même beaucoup  d'autres contextes dont les apparences sont trompeuses; cependant, ici le ngram n'est utilisé que pour prouver que le mot « import » occurre bien dans le langage, qu'il soit considéré comme un nom ou une abréviation. Le fait qu'il soit porté dans le reverso avec pour acception « importation » montre qu'il s'y trouve selon cette acception, que l'on veuille l'appeler mot normal ou abréviation. Les textes anglais mal classifiés et autres éléments de cette sorte, au même titre que le terme linguistique comptent pour peu.

Comment: Comptent pour peu ?? Tu es sérieux là ? Google nous dit trouver *import* dans seize ouvrages entre 1672 et 1968. La **moitié** (8) sont en fait rédigés en anglais, deux sont mal lus car il est écrit *importation*, deux sont inclus dans les mots *import-export* et *export-import*, deux correspondent à d'autres abréviations, *importants* et *importance*, et un n'est pas analysable (pas de texte disponible). Un seul correspond à l'abréviation d'importation.

Comment: La liste en question: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22import%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1672,cd_max:1968,lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=hvsGXNOiAdHGaZvdt9AJ&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjT_cbbmIffAhVRYxoKHZvuDZo4ChDy0wMISQ&biw=1482&bih=692&dpr=1

Comment: @jlliagre Très précisément, quelle partie de ma réponse serait fausse? Pas tout? Si?

Comment: Ta réponse semble affirmer qu'un mot absent du TLFi est "anormal" : *Normalement on ne devrait trouver ni « import » ni « export » dans le français sauf dans le mot composé « import-export »*  puis s'appuie sur une analyse erronée des résultat de ngram: *cependant, chose bizarre un ngram montre que les deux sont individuellement utilisés depuis longtemps déjà, et de plus, il sont plus fréquemment utilisés que le nom composé*, plus loin tu écrit: *la fréquence vérifiable dans l'ngram*.  Il faudrait que tu définisses *longtemps déjà* et donnes des exemples qui appuient tes affirmations.

Comment: Il y a aussi un lien "cassé" pour *acception de « import » en linguistique*

Comment: Et connais-tu le sens usuel d'**intromission** ?

Comment: @jlliagre Maintenant je le connais, au moins pour quelques temps :  (TLFi) [Intromission d'une pers.] LITT. **Synon. de introduction**. 
B. **Action par laquelle un corps ou un organe est introduit ou pénètre dans un autre.** Le sens usuel serait le premier, le second semble assez technique . Il semble qu'il n'y ait pas besoin d'ajouter ça…

Comment: Fais attention aux liens que tu postes, les liens de résultats de recherche sont éphémères. Un lien vers le TLFi ressemble à ça : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intromission

Comment: Et pourquoi mettre au conditionnel *serait une abréviation* alors que c'est une évidence ?